# can u guys help me to check the raw_tx that i've made?

Tags: createrawtransaction

so **i just** learnt how to **created a raw coinbase transaction**, **and i need to confirm if the format is correct, can you guys help me with this?**

: this is just an example it doesnt exists in the blockchain network

im using BIP34 transaction format and my wallet address is

```
address: 1Htcz9y5sVuztuwTnfpWR4dhqirhLMcK7r
```

this is the raw transaction format:

```
01000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ffffffff0e03fc7903036370756d696e657203000000000100f90295000000001976a914b9454405a39efcb023127cd6daacf9c133b84df388ac00000000
```

extract format:

```
01000000 .............................. Version
01 .................................... Number of inputs
| 00000000000000000000000000000000
| 00000000000000000000000000000000 ...  Previous outpoint TXID
| ffffffff ............................ Previous outpoint index
|
| 0e .................................. Bytes in coinbase
| |
| | 03 ................................ Bytes in height
| | | fc7903 .......................... Height: 227836
| |
| | 036370756d696e657203 .............. Arbitrary data
| 00000000 ............................ Sequence

01 .................................... Output count
| 00f9029500000000 .................... Satoshis (25 BTC)
| 1976a914b9454405a39efcb023127cd6
| daacf9c133b84df388ac ................ P2PKH script
| 00000000 ............................ Locktime
```

Did i get all that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend you use `bitcoin-cli` to check if the transaction you made is both syntactically and semantically correct. You can do so by running `bitcoin-cli decoderawtransaction`:

```
bitcoin-cli decoderawtransaction 01000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ffffffff0e03fc7903036370756d696e657203000000000100f90295000000001976a914b9454405a39efcb023127cd6daacf9c133b84df388ac00000000
```

That returns:

```
{
  "txid": "58857ef49cdfe7dc036bb0eb2463464aed859aae4abee915808ee51357e15abe",
  "hash": "58857ef49cdfe7dc036bb0eb2463464aed859aae4abee915808ee51357e15abe",
  "version": 1,
  "size": 99,
  "vsize": 99,
  "weight": 396,
  "locktime": 0,
  "vin": [
    {
      "coinbase": "03fc7903036370756d696e657203",
      "sequence": 0
    }
  ],
  "vout": [
    {
      "value": 25.00000000,
      "n": 0,
      "scriptPubKey": {
        "asm": "OP_DUP OP_HASH160 b9454405a39efcb023127cd6daacf9c133b84df3 OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG",
        "desc": "addr(mxQaHD44gXMFg2R5WEntEyr2hiTQFvZkwi)#80h6hw5r",
        "hex": "76a914b9454405a39efcb023127cd6daacf9c133b84df388ac",
        "address": "mxQaHD44gXMFg2R5WEntEyr2hiTQFvZkwi",
        "type": "pubkeyhash"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The fact that the command doesn't fail already tells you that the transaction is syntactically correct. With respect to semantics, it looks to me that it achieves exactly what you were going after.

Comment: Yeaayyyy, thanks a lot sirr